# Creating a new column based on condition of another column?

Tags: sql

| id | date | value | isLive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 | 9 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/3/2022 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/5/2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/2/2022 | 9 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/3/2022 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 2 | 0 |

I want to create a new column (value1) that checks whether isLive=0 and then if so outputs the value where the last row isLive=1

Transformed table

| id | date | value | isLive | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1/2/2022 | 9 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 1/3/2022 | 5 | 0 | 9 |
| 1 | 1/5/2022 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1/2/2022 | 9 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 1/3/2022 | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 2 | 0 | 5 |

Any SQL language is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am going emulate a solution I have used for filling down (like Excel) columns with null values.

```
WITH tmp1
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN islive > 0 THEN value
      ELSE NULL
    END AS value_tmp
    CASE 
      WHEN islive = 0 THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END AS ChangeIndicator
  FROM your_table
),
tmp2
AS
(
  SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(ChangeIndicator) OVER (ORDER BY id, date) AS RowGroup 
  FROM tmp1
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN value_tmp IS NOT NULL THEN value_tmp
    ELSE FIRST_VALUE(value_tmp) OVER (PARTITION BY RowGroup)
  END AS value1
FROM tmp2
```

Here, I have first created a columns called `value_tmp`, which basically contains `value` if `isLive > 0` and `null` otherwise.

I have also created a column called `ChangeIndicator`, which will indicate  if a change has taken place. Basically, if `isLive = 0`, it will be 0 and 1 otherwise.

Now, I will create a running total over the `ChangeIndicator`. This will allow me to put the rows into groups.

Finally, I can use the `FIRST_VALUE()` window function by partitioning over `RowGroup` in order to fill in the null values.

Comment: Yes, but there could be consecutive rows where isLive=0. Your approach won't work for the second consecutive rows and greater

Comment: I have come up with another solution that I think will work. Please let me know if there any errors, since I was not able to run this over your actual data.